# button action header section of uicollectionview in ios obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(handleTapGuesture)];

[headerView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

This code not work for me

In my `UiCollectionView` I added button in header section part..so when i click on more button..i want index of that cell.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGuesture)];
[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
headerView.tag = section;  
headerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[headerView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

And in handleTapGuesture use below code to get section index

```
- (void)handleTapGuesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    int section = (int)gesture.view.tag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*in **Swift** with a slightly more elegant code*

You can add `func indexPathForSupplementaryElement(ofKind kind: String, at point: CGPoint) -> IndexPath?` method in extension of `UICollectionView`

```
extension UICollectionView {
    func indexPathForSupplementaryElement(ofKind kind: String, at point: CGPoint) -> IndexPath? {
        let targetRect = CGRect(origin: point, size: CGSize(width: 0.1, height: 0.1))
        guard let attributes = collectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesForElements(in: targetRect) else { return nil }

        return attributes.filter { $0.representedElementCategory == .supplementaryView && $0.representedElementKind == kind }.first?.indexPath
    }
}
```

and use this in your `UIViewController` for example like this

```
@IBAction func didSelectHeader(sender: UIView, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
        guard let point = event.allTouches?.first?.location(in: collectionView) ?? sender.superview?.convert(sender.center, to: collectionView) else { return }
        guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForSupplementaryElement(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, at: point) else { return }

        // do something with the indexPath
    }
```

the `indexPath.item` in our case is every time 0 but the indexPath.section is different, depending on the location of the header relative to the section of the `collectionView`